# How to access guest's Samba server on local network avoiding Window's share

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, network-shares, samba

At the moment I'm having trouble getting anyone to log on to the network (via `\\26.x.x.x` IP), so typing `\\26.x.x.x` in Explorer redirects to Windows's computer, not linux's Samba.
It's possible to connect via `\\192.168.x.x`.

In the future I plan to do separate hosting, but at the moment I'm using VirtualBox and Lubuntu.

Comment: You should be able to use smb://ip_address_of_Linux/sambashare to address the Linux machine without using Windows.

Comment: Using smb:// asks to find an application that can open smb links. I downloaded SMB components from the Control Panel but still don't working.

Comment: Did you set up Samba after installing?   Using smb:// asks to find an application that can open smb links.  ... Not on my Ubuntu system.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I can connect via 192.168.177.6 and see share.

Comment: The US Department of Defence owns 26.0.0.0/8 & may not be happy for you to be playing in it ;) You cannot just assign yourself a non-private IP address & hope that it will work.

Comment: It's Radmin VPN so i don't know :). Only problem is just connecting via it, explorer sends me to my pc instead of linux guest.
I can't use smb protocol in explorer.
Also I can connect to my web server by it's ip.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to indicate that the IP address your attempting to use is a VPN.  Since as it's currently written is sounds like a question where your asking to do something, but that something is using the incorrect address, considering the address of the actual samba share is actually working.  I assume the samba server is connected to the same VPN as the client?